Proving we can minimize the number of crossings by having a planar embedding of $K_{2,2}$ encircle another out of any 2 such embeddings
Say that we draw a graph in the following way: we first draw $n$ planar embeddings of $K_{2,2}$ (that is, we first draw $n$ quadrilaterals) such there are no edges which cross. Then for each of the $K_ {2,2}$'s, we color 2 of its vertices red, 2 of its vertices blue, such that no edge connects vertices of the same color. Finally, for every planar embedding of $K_{2,2}$, for all of its red vertices, we draw an edge to every single blue vertex in our drawing.
I am trying to prove that if $c$ is the smallest amount of crossings out of any drawing which is produced by the above schema, that there exists a drawing with $c$ crossings where all of the planar embeddings of $K_{2,2}$ were drawn "inside" each other- that is, for any 2 planar embeddings of $K_{2,2}$, one of these embeddings completely encircles another.
For context, I am studying the properties of bipartite graph drawings, and have thought of this question myself as it could be of use in my research, and the statement I am trying to prove seemed intuitively plausible. I would be highly appreciative of any help towards showing either the truth or falsehood of the provided statement.

I think with two of these $4$-cycles, the minimum number of edge-crossings is four, and that can be achieved without one $4$-cycle being inside the other one.

@GerryMyerson you are correct; I actually meant to ask a slightly different claim, which was whether the minimum number of crossings can be realized with the cycles inside of each other. I have edited the question.

If I understood well, you're practically asking Zarankiewicz's conjecture: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ZarankiewiczsConjecture.html
